# How to arrive at desired equality?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Why is the following second equality true?

$$e^{1+1/2+...+1/(n+1)} - e^{1+1/2+...+1/n} \\= e^{1+1/2+...+1/n}\left(e^{1/(n+1)}-1\right)\\=e^{1+1/2+...+1/n}-\log(n)*\frac{e^{1/(n+1)}-1}{1/(n+1)}*\frac{n}{n+1}.$$

The first equality is clear, we simply factored out $e^{1+1/2+...+1/n}$. However, I can't see how we get the second equality. I played about with it for a while but nothing I do seems to give the desired result.

Please show me what manipulations do the trick.

Comment: $n$ is a natural number, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the second equality is not true for $n=1$ :
$$\left(e(\sqrt e-1)=\right)e^{1/1}\left(e^{1/(1+1)}-1\right)\not =e^{1/1}-\log(1)*\frac{e^{1/(1+1)}-1}{1/(1+1)}*\frac{1}{1+1}\left(=e\right).$$

Comment: Great point, I haven't noticed that. However, later we take the limit as $n\to\infty$, so it should be true for sufficiently large $n$, unless there is a mistake in this book. :)